# Browser related display issue with Synology Docker

Tags: windows-10, browser, nas, docker, synology

This is a new problem, but I have not checked this scenario in months so don't know when it might have started.

```
Synology DS-718+  (on local network)
DSM 6.2.4-25556
Docker 18.09.0-0519
Windows 10x64 Pro
```

When I navigate `Docker => Container`, the window (Tab) initially shows my two running containers, but then, after less than one second, the window content disappears and remains that way.

The containers are definitely running.

This occurs with both Microsoft Edge and Chrome browsers.
Internet Explorer displays this page normally.
The Edge and Chrome browser will display this page normally in **Private or Incognito mode**.

I have cleared the browser cache and ensured pop-ups are not being blocked for the URL.

I have re-started my NAS with no change in behavior

Any assistance welcomed.